# Trying To Get Bot To Post In Specific Channel Based Off A JSON File

Tags: node.js, json, discord, discord.js

The bot will save the data to the JSON file but I can't figure out how to call that data back so the bot remembers the correct channel to post the message in.

```
bot.on("message" , (message) =>{
if (message.content.startsWith ("!config enable")) {
  editedmessage = message.content.slice (15);

bot.msgs = {
   channelName: editedmessage
}

fs.writeFile ("./storage/clanConfig.json", JSON.stringify (bot.msgs, null, 4), (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;})
  message.channel.send ("channel saved");
}

let channel = (channelName);
let counter = 0;

if(++counter === 10){
      bot.channels.cache.get(channelName).send(`10 messages were sent`)
        counter = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make these changes.

- Move `counter` outside of the event handler.
  You don't want to set the counter to 0 with every message anyway.
- Use `message.content.split(/\s+/)[2]` to get the channel name from the message.
  This is lenient against extra spaces (`"!config  enable  bla bla"`) and only takes the first word after "enable".
- Add a function that determines if a new channel name is even valid.
  Don't accept user input blindly, always do a validity check.
- Use `writeFileSync` to write the config to disk.
  With a file this small there won't be any noticeable delay, and it makes sure that there is no race condition (otherwise the `.send()` could happen before the config file has finished writing).
- Use the config variable `bot.msgs.channelName` directly when you need it, instead of maintaining a separate `channelName` variable.

Code:

```
bot.msgs = {
  channelName: "last channel from config file, otherwise default value"
};

var counter = 0;

bot.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("!config enable")) {
    let newChannel = message.content.split(/\s+/)[2];

    if (isValid(newChannel)) {
      bot.msgs.channelName = newChannel;
      fs.writeFileSync("./storage/clanConfig.json", JSON.stringify(bot.msgs, null, 4)
      message.channel.send("channel saved");
      counter = 0;
    }
  } 

  if (++counter === 10) {
    bot.channels.cache.get(bot.msgs.channelName).send(`10 messages were sent to {bot.msgs.channelName}.`)
    counter = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: `bot.channels.cache.get(bot.msgs.channelName).send(`10 messages were sent to {bot.msgs.channelName}.`)`
` seems to throw an error.

Comment: TypeError: bot.msgs.channelName.send is not a function

Comment: Also this error trying to add the channel to the database `ReferenceError: isValid is not defined`